# AWS S3 private link not working with aws-cli or boto3

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3, aws-cli

I am trying to access my S3 bucket using private link (private access point), now that I have successfully created it it shows three options to access my bucket privately

1. ARN format address of bucket
2. s3:// Uri to access bucket
3. Another unique address

I tried all of these in python boto3 and aws-cli to access my bucket privately so following code works without using any of the above endpoints but if I uncomment the endpoint_url in params, it simply not works, the same endpoint also not works with aws-cli s3 command

```
from botocore.client import Config
from boto3 import Session
import json

session = Session()
params = { 
    "service_name": "s3",
    "config": Config(connect_timeout=5, retries={'max_attempts': 1}),
    #"endpoint_url": "s3://arn:aws:s3:******/s3testlink"
}

data = {
    "userId": 1,
    "status": False,
    "message": "Some thing is still pending"
}

s3 = session.resource(**params)
data = json.dumps(data, indent=4).encode('utf-8')
object = s3.Object('test', 'some/path/file.json')
result = object.put(Body=data)
```

What I tried to solve this problem is following

- Created a gateway endpoint in the same VPC but didn't work
- Created s3 interface endpoint in same VPC but it also didn't work
- Just to check I created a test VPN client in the same VPC connected my workstation to that VPN and tried but all in vain
- Tried all three address types shown in private link tab in S3 section but still not worked

Comment: Yes i tried but it says invalid access point or access point not resolved

Comment: You need to make sure that the S3 endpoint is correctly configured. For the gateway endpoint, have you associated the subnets in which the (presumably EC2) environment is running?

Comment: My Ec2 is in separate VPC as i want to directly access S3 bipassing the need of EC2